# Problemas con crear aparecer input

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con lo siguiente. Resulta que quiero crear elementos input dependientes de una cantidad seleccionada en un select-option. Por ejemplo si se selecciona un valor del select como 3, crear esos 3 input y asi sucesivamente. hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:
Una función que obtiene los valores y una variable con los input que debo de poner

```
function showInput() {
    getSelectElement = document.getElementById("vias").value;
    if (getSelectElement == 0) {
        alert("Seleccione un numero válido");
    }else{

        construirInput = 1;
        while( construirInput <= getSelectElement){
            colocar = "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10 '><label class='form-check-label'>Calle</label><input class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Ingresar Calle' name='calle'></div><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10 '><label class='form-check-label'>Por calle</label><input class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Por Calle' name='cruceA[]'></div><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10 '><label class='form-check-label'>Y</label><input class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Y' name='cruceB[]'></div>";

            $('#ubicacion').html(colocar);
            construirInput++;
        }

    }
}
```

mientras que los select están enumerados del uno al 10 como:

```
<select name="vias" id="vias" class="form-control" onchange="showInput()">
    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

para colocarlo solo un div con un ID = "ubicacion". Pueden ayudarme con esto...

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. ¿Deseas crear 3 elementos tipo `input` o deseas crear tantos elementos `input` como se seleccionen de la lista?. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco eso? Saludos

Comment: se podía ver como crear tantos elementos input dependiendo de un valor seleccionado en un select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo le hice unas pequeñas modificaciones:

1. Agregué el elemento `div` con `id="ubicacion"`.
2. En el evento `onchange` del elemento `select`, envío `this` como parámetro, para que esté disponible en la función `showInput()` y así obtener el valor del `select`.
3. Y cambié el bucle `while` por un bucle `for` (me gustan más jeje).

El código quedaría algo así:

```js
function showInput(select) {
    var str = '';
    if (select.value == 0) {
        alert("Seleccione un numero válido");
    }else{
     /*Ciclo para que se ejecute el numero de veces*/
     for (var i = 0; i < select.value; i++) 
   str+='<input type="text" ><br>';
  $('#ubicacion').html(str);

    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<select name="vias" id="vias" class="form-control" onchange="showInput(this)">
    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<div id="ubicacion">
</div>
```